# Angular 8 http.get bind a certain property only

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-http

Is there a way for angular http.get to deserialize a json object without the need of the root object?

json:

```
{
        "jsonprop" : [
            {
                "id" : 1,
                "name" : "testName"
            },
            {
                "id" : 2,
                "name" : "testName2"
            }
        ]
}
```

models:

```
export interface Jsonprop {
    id: number;
    name: string;
}

export interface RootObject {
    jsonprop: Jsonprop[];
}
```

http method: **(working but this is not what i wanted)**

```
getJsonProp(searchText: string): Observable<RootObject> {
    return this.http.get<RootObject>('apiurl');            
}
```

What I wanted to do instead is :

```
getJsonProp(searchText: string): Observable<Jsonprop[]> {
    return this.http.get<Jsonprop[]>('apiurl');            
}
```

Is there a way for me to do this?

Comment: Use the map operator. https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/map. This is typically the very first operator you learn when learning RxJS. Maybe you should take some time reading about it: it's fundamental stuff.

Comment: So am I correct that it is only the typings that are causing you issue? If so then yes, you can use map to project all values to a new observable which you can better-define

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`map()`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/map) operator from RxJS. For eg:

```
return this.http.get<RootObject>('apiurl').pipe(
   map(response) => {
      return response.jsonprop;
   })
);
```

Comment: Thanks @Nicholas K it seems we have a differnet version of angular but this gave me an idea how to make it worked.